# How can I have a Linux machine join a Windows Domain?

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory

Sorry if I am misusing terms here; I actually don't know much about Active Directory and the related technologies.  Basically I have a Linux computer and I'd like it (or my user on that computer) to be associated with my user on the Domain, so that I can browse the network and all that stuff windows has.

Is this feasible?  What do I need to look into to do something like this?

Answer (score 10):

There are three main options:

- Kerberos plus LDAP - This is a lower-level option where you set up Linux to use Active Directory's underlying protocols yourself.  Described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/76803#76815).
- Samba - Samba is the de facto standard for joining a Linux machine to a Windows domain.
- [Microsoft Windows Services for Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_Services_for_UNIX) includes options for serving usernames to Linux / UNIX via NIS and for synchronizing passwords to Linux / UNIX machines.  You'd use this if you wanted to do *everything possible* from Windows or if you had an existing Linux / UNIX infrastructure you wanted to tie to Windows; for most environments, though, one of the other solutions would be better.

There are a few other options available too: Likewise (apparently no longer available), Centrify, SSSD...  There's further discussion in [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/845778/8437).

Comment: +1 for Likewise. Likewise Open has saved me hundreds of hours in user administration. I specifically built an AD infrastructure for my Linux boxes. Way, way way way way better.

Comment: Likewise appears to be dead; at least your link goes to some unrelated business and searching doesn't turn up much.

Comment: Likewise was purchased by Isilon (now DellEMC) for inclusion in their NAS.  I guess they did away with the standalone product.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways that I know of.  From the linux host you can try this:

root#  net ads join -UAdministrator%password

Or you can just create the computer object in active directory.

Like everyone else said, you'll need to add the samba packages to get that to happen.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at an excellent public domain package called Samba.  It might very well be part of the Linux distribution that you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all the benefits and security of AD, you'll need a solution involving Kerberos (for authentication) and LDAP (for authorization). There's an excellent tutorial [here](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2007/01/15/linux-ad-integration-version-4/) that I've used in the past and it works amazingly well. It's more complex to implement than just using samba/winbindd, but you'll get the benefit of being able to use the UNIX attributes in AD to manage your linux users, groups, uids, gids, etc.

Comment: I believe that Samba/Winbind can use AD's UNIX attributes as well, using the idmap_ad backend (http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/idmap_ad.8.html) and the "winbind nss info" smb.conf setting (http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#id2564796) setting.

Comment: Heh, news to me :-) That's a nice feature to have. I guess I still prefer the security that Kerberos brings, but for more simple setups, this will probably be just fine.

Comment: I don't find that tutorial excellent at all. For example, it says "Make sure that the appropriate Kerberos libraries, OpenLDAP, pam_krb5, and nss_ldap are installed. If they are not installed, install them.", without any more details.

Comment: @FrankH. You'll notice that this answer is 7 years old. If you have a better tutorial that you can link to, by all means edit my answer accordingly. However, if you are a linux sysadmin, being able to install packages without step-by-step instructions are among the first things one should learn.

Comment: Since I'm asking this, it should be quite obvious that I'm not a linux admin, don't you think?

Comment: @FrankH. You are a professional. You cannot reasonably expect to do your job by following perfectly comprehensive, step-by-step instructions for every single task that you need to do. Some level of initiative is required to go out and actually **learn** the operating systems you're using. If you're unable or unwilling to do that, then hire someone to help you out. There's no shame in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

same tips 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-join-a-windows-2003-active-directory-domain-from-linux-system.html

Comment: Also a non-tutorial which just tells you in very broad terms what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Samba/Likewise is overkill.

Set up pam_krb5, authenticating to the KDC of the AD domain.

Answer (score 0):

To add a Linux machine to an Active Directory domain, you will need:

- TCP / IP Config: Configure the DNS of the AD as DNS.
- NTP Config: Configure the NTP server in DC
- Packages: Install the necessary packages
- SSSD Configuration: Configure the network authentication service.
- Verification with the id command

Here is a guide, step by step:

https://www.sysadmit.com/2019/11/linux-anadir-equipo-al-dominio-windows.html