# linux in domain?

Tags: linux

there is a requirement to be in windows domain in our network. It will be monitored. Up till now I just got ip from dhcp without much worrying. What do I have to do in order to have my linux station in domain. Or is it possible without? And not to be discovered? Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have a Linux machine join a Windows Domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/76803/how-can-i-have-a-linux-machine-join-a-windows-domain)

Comment: Discuss this with your system administrator. The part about "And not to be discovered" suggests you are intending to break rules imposed by one of our fellow admins, so would probably go down like a lead baloon.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to domain a linux machine. Samba has supported this for quite some time. Some Linux distributions have a wizard that'll guide you through the process. You'll need some information to make it work, such as the name of at least one Domain Controller, and a domain username for the domaining process itself.

**Ubuntu** [A nice guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto)

**OpenSUSE** [The guide for the SLES distribution](http://www.novell.com/documentation/sles10/sles_admin/data/sec_samba_adnet.html), but still applies to openSUSE 11.2

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 alternatives to authenticate against Active Directory:

1.Using the kerberos client

2.Using Winbind & samba client

Linux systems can authenticate against a domain but cannot participate in the functions provided by active directory management. For most current distros there is a kerberos wizard.  Windbind (part of samba) allows linux to see AD users and groups as unix user and groups.  Samba provides file and print services for all clients using the SMB/CIFS protocol.

All that being said you are likely to be monitored using WMI calls- which will fail on a linux machine