# adding linux workstation to windows Active Directory

Tags: linux

we have windows Active Directory , i want to join my linux node to this windows Domain 
can u suggest what to do ...for authentication??
is it possible with samba or ldap ...or anything else
can u shown out by example

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have a Linux machine join a Windows Domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/76803/how-can-i-have-a-linux-machine-join-a-windows-domain)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. [Here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Authenticating-Linux-Active-Directory.html) is a good example for **SuSE** linux.

And [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto) is the manual for **Ubuntu** linux.

I think that there is no universal way for all linux distributions, but for each of them you can find individual way to connect it to AD.